# One Form Submit Action controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a form,on click submit the value should pass to 2 controllers in codeigniter

Here is my **form**

```
<?php echo form_open('Test/form_1')?>  <?php //echo form_open('Test/form_2')?>
    <input name="fname"  type="text" />
    <input name="Lname"  type="text" />
    <input name="Sname"  type="text" />
    <input type="submit"  value="Continue">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller 1**

```
function form_1 ()  {
    // do something 
}

function form_2 ()  {
    // do something 
}
```

i need something like this:

```
<?php echo form_open('Test/form_1'),('Test/form_2')?>
```

I know its wrong but how it can be done in `codeigniter`

Comment: you can do it using ajax, send the post request to first URL, on success of first you can send second request too.

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible to send one to double action if you trying to do this there is another way to this see in example

**Example**

```
<?php echo form_open('Test/form_1')?>  
    <input name="fname"  type="text" />
    <input name="Lname"  type="text" />
    <input name="Sname"  type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Continue">
    <input type="submit" name="no"  value="cancel">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
    function form_1 ()  {
     if(isset($_POST['yes'])){
        // do some thing or send to another function
     } elseif (isset($_POST['no'])) {
        // do some thing or send to another function
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Submit your form to **form_1**
- Perform what ever actions you need there
- Call **form_2** from **form_1** (as an internal function). In **form_2** you can have a flag so that you don't render a view but instead return some values back to **form_1**

Answer (score 0):

you can use an ajax function

```
$('#form_id').on('submit', function() {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        var form  = this;
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo site_url("test/form_1"); ?>',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo site_url("test/form_2"); ?>',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    };
    return false;
});
```